# Element in VueJS template reference self

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a component which will have many div elements, with only one having an 'active' class on click. I'm trying to bind the 'active' class if a variable 'activeSlide' is equal to the element.

```
v-bind:class="{ 'active': activeSlide === ?? }"
```

I'm just not sure what the `??` should be. I haven't been able to find anything that tells how an element can reference itself. Or maybe there is a better approach?

My Code in .vue component file:

```
<template>
  <div v-on:click="show" v-bind:class="{ 'active': activeSlide === ?? }"></div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
        return {
            activeSlide: null
        }
    }
    methods: {
       show: function(e) {
           this.activeSlide = e.target;
       }
    } 
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would assume that the `??` is intended to be something uniquely identifying to the active element.

```
<template>
  <div v-on:click="show('Slide1')" v-bind:class="{ 'active': activeSlide === 'Slide1' }"></div>

  <div v-on:click="show('Slide2')" v-bind:class="{ 'active': activeSlide === 'Slide2' }"></div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
        return {
            activeSlide: null
        }
    }
    methods: {
       show: function(value) {
           this.activeSlide = value;
       }
    } 
}
</script>
```

So basically when you click the slide it will change the `activeSlide` property to the value passed into the `v-on:click` method.

There are more dynamic ways of doing this such as if you were to loop through a series of elements you could then compare the active index to the index of the element instead of explicitly saying `Slide1` or `Slide2`.

Here is a dynamic example

```
<template>
  <div v-for="slide in slides" :key="slide.id" v-on:click="show(slide.id)" v-bind:class="{ 'active': activeSlide === slide.id }"></div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
        return {
            activeSlide: null
        }
    }
    methods: {
       show: function(value) {
           this.activeSlide = value;
       }
    } 
}
</script>
```

so you can use any available data in the iteration to compare, just pass in `slide.whatever` to the method and set the class to equal the same thing.

Comment: This would be a way to do it. It will be dynamic, because the slides will be populated from an array. However, a slide's index could change. If the user moves a slide in the view it will update the array, which is why I was looking to see if possible to reference the element itself. Because a user can switch between multiple presentations, the identifier here would need to be so unique that no other slide would have it.

Comment: @JustinD, if your looping through an array it doesn't have to be the index. I mean I don't know what your array of data looks like but I will post an example.

Comment: No, I get that. I just though that it could be simpler than coming up with a unique identifier, where I could reference the element itself.

Comment: @JustinD, well you would have trouble accessing the elements attributes for the `v-bind:class`. I would rely on the data to be the unique identifier if possible. Added an update with new dynamic example.

Comment: Your example will work. Just to clarify, I was trying to access the element itself... $this or the like. Didn't know if it was possible in Vue.

Comment: @JustinD, well if I am understanding you right there are ways to access the element you just couldn't do it directly on the element, you would have to use the `ref` attribute and the `id` attribute on the element and then call `this.$refs.id.whatever_id` in a method, if that makes sense...